# Can't emit to specific room in Flask using SocketIO

Tags: flask, flask-socketio, chatroom

I'm trying to join a room and emit for all members of the room but I'm having some trouble.When I change the line room = room to broadcast = True it works.Would really appreciate some help.

Server-side :

```
@socketio.on("room")
def room(room):
    currentroom = room["room"]
    join_room(currentroom)
    
@socketio.on("message")
def mes(message):
    room = message['room']
    emit('add', {'msg' : message['msg']},room = room)
```

Client-side :

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    

    socket.on('connect', () => {
          window.onclick = function (e) {
            if (e.target.localName == 'a') {
               room = e.target.innerHTML;
               localStorage.setItem('room',room);
               socket.emit('room', {'room' :room});
            }
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('new-message').onsubmit = () => {
            console.log(4);
            console.log(document.getElementById('input-message').value);
            console.log(localStorage.getItem('room'));
            socket.emit('message',{'msg' : document.getElementById('input-message').value,'room' : localStorage.getItem('room')});
    };
    socket.on('add', data => {
            console.log(6);
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            p.innerHTML = data.msg;
            document.querySelector(".message-side").appendChild(p);
    });
});
```

Comment: list the problems you're facing.

Comment: I get the room when an a link is clicked, send the specified room to the server,when i submit the "new-message" form i emit to message : the message and the current room which i stored previously in local storage,but nothing gets emitted back to the client

Comment: instead of switching to `broadcast=True`, try hardcoding the room name in your `room()` and `mes()` functions. Does it work then? If it does, then this is a bug in your room handling.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it by preventing reloading with e.preventDefault()